# How can I copy a NFC badge to my (rooted) Android phone for Daily Usage

Tags: root-access, nfc, xposed-framework

For the Cafeteria a school we have NFC badges with which we pay meals or drinks.
I was wondering how is it possible to have the card on my phone? I lost it 5 times last year.

I've tried to copy the data on the card this didn't work so I possibly need to emulate the card on the phone.
Like i said it would be usefull to use it in such way and gives me something to brag about to my non geeky friends. B-) 
My phone is rooted, Xposed Framework is installed (when this helps) I have Android 4.1.2 on My Xperia P it's stock.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Not tested myself, but from its description [NFC Porter](http://www.appbrain.com/app/cz.ima.nfc.p2pid) looks like to be your candidate: *replaces all identification cards and unifies them under a mobile app*. Please let me know if that's what you're after – I will then make it an answer with some additional details.

Comment: Thanks Izzi it wasnt wat I'm  looking  for but seems i just haveto get the key of my lunch card.

Comment: The app will create a badge nativly and not port it from a badge, what i need to be done. So i will try this app and see what i can achoeve with it. Thanks for your Help

Comment: A closer look at their Pro version made me doubt as well it was your choice. Didn't see such an app yet (but definitely got your point). I'm just setting up [a list of NFC apps](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=208) you might wish to check with later (maybe in a few hours). Far from being complete, but if I jump into a candidate you'll find it there.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the type of card used in your school, copying is not a simple task: The data is may be **cryptographically protected** and you need to **emulate the UID**, an ID which gets transmitted by the card early in the communication process. Here are some tips:

- At first you need to find out which type of NFC Tag our card is. You can use [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=at.mroland.android.apps.nfctaginfo&hl=de) app from the Google Play Store
- If the card is a *MIFARE Classic* Tag you might be able to clone the data on it. These cards have had some security problems in the past.
- Emulating the UID is not possible by default on Android ([related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26851910/android-nfc-card-emulation-with-fixed-uid))

  - But we developed an App which is capable of emulating the UID on some Android devices, for more information see the first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37077371/6379805)
  - It is also possible that your badge only uses its UID to know who you are. In this case there is no data saved on your card. If this is the case the app for emulating the UID could already be enough to have a badge on your smartphone ;-)

I hope this helps.